# Post data not submitting properly with jQuery form plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, post, uploading, jquery-forms-plugin

**Background**: I'm working on a management page for musicians. Lets say the user creates an album, then uploads a song into the album. I'm using ajax posts with *the jQuery form plugin*.

First, I worked on uploading songs into existing albums (works great).

Then, I worked on creating new albums and showing up without a refresh using .append() and .attr (works great).

Now I'm working on uploading a song to the album that showed up thanks to the append()'s.

**Problem**: When the album that is created is prepared, it's grand. All the values and functions are the exact same as the album loaded when the page renders.

When I attempt to upload a song, I get an error server-side. It takes the exact same functions i'm using to upload a song to the ajaxed album as the initial page rendering album.

I refresh the page, and I can upload a song.

I'm using jQuery.form plugin, and I thought it would be because the function was inside the $(document).ready(function { ... }

the uploading script:

```
$('form#uploadSongToAlbum').submit(function() { 
  $(this).ajaxSubmit({
    target: 'login/uploadSongToAlbum.php',
    dataType:  'html',
    beforeSubmit: function() { 
      alert(showRequest);
      $.jGrowl("Uploading... hold on...<br />", { life:1000 });
    }, 
    success: function() {
      selectUploadedID(); 
    },
    error: function() {
      $.jGrowl(textStatus, {  header:"<span style='color:red'>Error:</span>", sticky: true });
    }
  });
  return false; 
});
```

Now, looking further into the problem, I opened up the console in Chrome, went to network and recorded the posted requests for both the ajaxed upload and the page-loaded upload, and I discovered very different values.
Here are the ajaxed upload post values (this one breaks):

> **Form Data**:
>
> file:silence2.mp3
>
> album:80

and here are the page-loaded post values (this one works):

> **Request Payload**:
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryZpJpGxBLJEBRYadH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="silence2.mp3"
>      Content-Type: audio/mp3
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryZpJpGxBLJEBRYadH
>      Content-Disposition: form-data; name="album"
>      80
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryZpJpGxBLJEBRYadH--

Thank you soo much in advance, everyone. I must be doing something wrong. I can provide more code if necessary. Keep in mind: The html markup and values for both ajaxed albums and page-loaded albums *are* valid. It must be something jQuery that I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Can you show an example of the markup containing the file input elements?  Also the code that you are using to initialize your form plugin would be helpful.

Comment: Certainly. 
Here's the outputted file input code for Ajaxed:
http://www.oiledupbirds.com/1%20-%20ajaxedoutput.txt

and here's the outputted file input code for the page loaded, which works fine:
http://www.oiledupbirds.com/1%20-%20pageloaded%20output.txt

(I just noticed that there are two slashes next to the very first image src, and as that doesn't make sense to me before coffee, it shouldn't be the cause of this problem)

The code I'm using to initialize the form plugin is above, under "the uploading script:"

If you need anything else let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `enctype` attribute to the form tag of the dynamically created content:

```
<form id="uploadSongToAlbum" action="login/uploadSongToAlbum.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- snip... -->
</form>
```

Also, if your uploading script is called from within `$(document).ready`, it will only be called once when the page loads.  If you want it to apply to dynamically created forms, use the `live()' method:

```
$('form#uploadSongToAlbum').live('submit', function() { 
    // ajaxSubmit code here....
});
```